# $X^2+aX+b \in \mathbb{Z}[X] $ is irreducible mod $p$ ($p >2$ and prime) if and only if $a^2-4b$ is not a square mod $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For ,,$\Rightarrow$", assume that $a^2-4b = c^2$ with $c \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. I want to show that $\frac{-a \pm \sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2} = \frac{-a \pm c}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ so that I can conclude that $X^2+aX+b$ is reducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$. How do I do this?

Comment: You probably mean so you can conclude the polynomial is reducible?

Comment: You are doing the direction of is a square to being reducible?

Comment: @NeckverseHerdman Yes, thank you

Comment: @AHusain Yes, by using the contrapositive

Answer (score 0):

If $a^2 - 4b$ is a square modulo $p$, then we find $c$ such that $a^2 - 4b \equiv c^2 \mod p$. Then, set $t_{\pm} = 2^{-1} \cdot (-a \pm c)$, with $2^{-1}$ an integer inverse of $2$ modulo $p$, and show that your polynomial (seen as a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$) is equal to $(X - t_{-})(X - t_{+})$ by directly computing the expression in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$.

The other direction can be done by assuming $X^2 + aX + b$ is reducible modulo $p$, which implies we have $$X^2 + aX + b \equiv (X - x)(X - y) \mod p$$ for some integers $x$ and $y$. Computing the latter yields \begin{align*}
a &\equiv -(x + y) \mod p \\
 b & \equiv xy \: \quad \quad \: \: \, \mod p
\end{align*} and then $a^2 - 4b$ should be congruent modulo $p$ to the square $(x-y)^2.$